# azure devops api The user is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get a simple api sample project to work.  Nothing works, as I just keep getting the same error: TF400813: The user 'b370c683-bb42-626c-9a85-ec3a81c32fbf' is not authorized to access this resource.",

I was able to get a Token from micrsoftonline.com but I'm guessing it could be a setup issue in the azure portal or Azure Devops.  All the documentation is 100% useless, as every single piece of documentation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1 has samples that are 4 years old!  none of them work, and there are several walkthroughs that conflict one another.  I've been trying to get the service principal linked to azure app registration.  I thought I had that working, but every time I run the sample code, or try postman, it's just the same error every time.

I'm using the following in Postman:

[image: Headers:]

[image]

Get request as follows:

[https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=7.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7BOrganization%7D/_apis/projects?api-version=7.0)

Although, I almost never use Rest API's ever, so that may be incorrect, but keep getting the same error:

[image]

Sample code is from here:  https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples

4 years ago, LOL, probably way out of date    OH, By the way, I'm using azure 30 day trial, and just signed up for azure devops as well.  But there's no mention of any limitation.  It cant be this difficult to use azure as an app registration point to automate tasks in azure devops can it?

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: looks like you don't have enough access.  is this PAT is created by you? try to create a PAT with full access.

Comment: Definitely not a PAT.  That won't work.  I got the the token through login.microsoftonline.com

Comment: you can't use Bearer (JWT) token for this.. you have to create a PAT and use it in basic auth.
or (not sure if it will work) change the type from basic to bearer and then add your token

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'll try that.  According to other Stack overflow posts, it has to be a bearer.  Every post and every sample code is different, lol

Comment: you can use bearer token but you have to change the type then.

Comment: Just a blank response from postman now.  But 401 Unauthorized still.

Comment: What scope and grant_type you used to generate bearer token?

Comment: Now, I'm getting something else:     AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '65d2e247-56c3-4857-99e1-5600a569d9fa' was not found in the directory 'Default Directory'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Comment: Not sure what an application has to do with a user.  I get this while trying to create the token.  I'm just using the sample app from 4 years ago, lol.  I did delete an application, but that's because it never worked anyways, so just created a new app and new service principal.  also, the email address for devops and portal are the same.  I never assigned an app to a user.  I assigned a subscription yes, but not an app.

Comment: getting closer :) I think just create a new application on azure and use it..

Comment: @Sridevi not sure what grant type and scope.  No clue what that even means.  All documentation and code samples are 4 years old, and never work.

Comment: @Manish Ok, I'll try that..  Is there just a client library that makes it easy to use?  I never use REST as theres no need for it, until now.  I see client library for MSAL but not for azure devops

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops  follow this, it might help..

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Also, I'm using azure devops in the cloud.  Now I realize there is on prem?  So, probably all the documentation is mixed up as I can't really tell which is for which or if they are identical.

Comment: Thanks @Manish I followed this:  learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/   But, I don't actually have my site up and running.  Can I just put in placeholders for now?  It's asking for the application URL and sitename, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by download the following code sample:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample

This has a readme in the project which explains where and how to register your azure devops app.  no need for azure portal in this case.

there is a bug in the code however, you need to change /oauth/requesttoken in the index.cshtml page to /oauth/authorize

Also, you need to add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization in your project as it probably won't compile without that reference.

ALSO, make sure to test it with only a few scopes, as the scopes that you create your application with must match EXACTLY the scopes you use in your web.config.

You could also manually make the calls by following this document:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#2-authorize-your-app but it's a bit more work.  You'll need to create your REST calls manually.

ALSO, there is a major caching/propagation issue with azure and azure devops, as I had everything working perfectly, or so I thought, but kept getting the 401 error.  So, I came back half an hour later, without doing anything and it worked fine.  So, you may or may not run into that problem.

Also, when you call the rest API, using the following format:
GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=7.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/projects?api-version=7.0)
(This will get all projects in an organization as an example.)
There are several misleading examples, and it's painful if you are not an expert in REST.

Comment: Also, I didn't login to my default directory in Azure Devops.  So that was a problem.  But , no one even suggested that to me.  I had to figure that one on my own. But, of course that was critical.  It seems there is no complete documentation.  I might as well write it as it seems no one except me actually knows anything.  Also, make sure to connect your azure devops to Azure Active Directory (AAD) Default Directory in the azure dev.

Comment: You can do this by clicking on Azure Active directory in your organization settings in Azure Devops.  then connect to your default directory in AAD (if it's not already connected.)  That was a mistake on my part, but no one even suggested that. It would have saved me a hug amount of time,  had someone asked me to double check that..  (thanks to me myself and I Chris.)

Comment: Oh Also, when you do connect to AAD, it has unlimited scopes, not like the applications that are created in Azure devops themselves, and you a have to specify every single scope, and they must match in your configuration file.  So, this works great for development, but you may need to double check this when deploying to production

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are using bearer token, but as per the documentation you should use PAT.
How to generate a PAT [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows)

you can explore more from here about authentication [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops)

[image: docs]

Edit 1:
As mention on comment above, you can also try to change the auth type from basic to bearer.

Edit 2:
We can use rest api using oauth as mention on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops)
document. 
follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) to create an application.

Comment: Is there a client library for this?  Seems overly complex using REST API.